Required field on nullable object
I'm working on a Spring Boot app and am using openapi4j lib to validate incoming requests. I have OpenAPI definition yaml file where I defined schema against which validation will be performed. I have an issue with a nullable object which has required field of its own.
Basically, the object will either be null or it will need to have a required field set. I can achieve this with primitive types (string for instance), but I can't get it to work with object types. I've used this question as starting point: How to specify a property can be null or a reference with swagger
I want both of these requests to pass validation:

foo is null
{
  "foo": null
}


foo is set correctly
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 1
  }
}



And I need these to fail

foo not set:
{}


foo invalid, missing bar
{
  "foo": {}
}


EDIT another invalid input: bar invalid
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": null
  }
}



Here is my schema so far:
openapi: 3.0.3
...
paths:
...
  some/path:
    put:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              additionalProperties: false
              required:
                - foo
              properties:
                foo:
                  nullable: true
                  oneOf:
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
...
components:
  schemas:
    Foo:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      nullable: true
      required:
        - bar
      properties:
        bar:
          type: integer

When I test this with foo: null payload I get errors:
{
    "requestErrors": [
        {
            "schemaPath": "body.foo.<oneOf>.<#/components/schemas/Foo>.<required>",
            "instancePath": "body.foo",
            "message": "Field 'bar' is required."
        }
    ]
}


If you change the foo property to foo:  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo', does it work? The Foo schema itself is nullable, so there's no need to mark the property as nullable.

{"foo":null} and {} are essentially same requests.

@Helen it does not work, the only difference is that schemaPath changes in the error message to body.foo.<#/components/schemas/Foo>.<required>

This will satisfy {"foo": null}
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Test
  description: 'A test api'
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://examples.com
paths:
  '/api/v1/thing':
    post:
      summary: a summary
      requestBody:
        description: OK
        content:
          'application/json':
            schema:
              required:
                - foo
              oneOf:
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    foo:
                      type: string
                      maxLength: 0
                      nullable: true
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    foo:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/foo_bar'
            examples:
              foo_null_valid:
                value: { 'foo': { 'bar': null } }
              foo_bar_string_error:
                value: { 'foo': { 'bar': '1' } }
              foo_integer_valid:
                value: { 'foo': { 'bar': 1 } }
              foo_nullable_valid:
                value: { 'foo': null }
              foo_empty_string_valid:
                value: { 'foo': '' }
              foo_string_error:
                value: { 'foo': '1' }
              foo_bar_nullable_valid:
                value: { 'foo': { 'bar': null } }
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema: {}
components:
  schemas:
    foo_bar:
      title: foo_bar
      type: object
      required:
        - bar
      properties:
        bar:
          nullable: true
          type: integer





the error messaging on this is a little funky because of the use of oneOf.  OpenAPI 3.0.x makes this more difficult than it should be because they limited the use of JSON Schema functionality in the earlier versions. This is much easier in OpenAPI 3.1.0+

I see what you are trying to do here with oneOf, but if I'm reading this correctly this would allow for "foo": "some string" which is not valid. also bar is not nullable under any circumstances. if foo is not null, bar has to be there and has to be integer

Oh you can add maxLength: 0 but other than that, there's no other way I know of to prevent {"foo": ""}.  The nullable keyword requires the use of the type keyword.

You had bar required so I just followed your example.  If it's a different behavior, share those constraints and someone can help you figure that out

i added more examples

foo_empty_string_valid is not valid input. foo can only be an object or null. I understand you made a workaround making foo a string to be able to make it nullable, but foo can not be a string, empty or non-empty. The workaround fixes one problem, but it opens up another

this is the limitation you will have with OAS 3.0.x and using nullable.  Maybe someone else has a solution, but I can't think of any other way to achieve your request

You can try what Helen suggested, removing the nullable from foo directly because your bar schema is already nullable.
Secondly, oneOf is unnecessary in this example.
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Test
  description: 'A test api'
  version: 1.0.0
servers: 
  - url: https://examples.com 
paths:
  '/api/v1/thing':
    get:
      summary: a summary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                type: object
                required: 
                  - foo
                properties:
                  foo:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/foo_bar'
              examples:
                foo_null_valid:
                  value: { 'foo': { 'bar': null } }
                foo_string_error:
                  value: { 'foo': { 'bar': '1' } }
                foo_integer_valid:
                  value: { 'foo': { 'bar': 1 } }
components:
  schemas:
    foo_bar:
      title: foo_bar
      type: object
      required:
        - bar
      properties:
        bar:
          nullable: true
          type: integer



The only error thrown is for invalid type on the second example.


bar: null is not valid foo: null is. if foo is not null, bar must be set

also the validation is performed on request body, not on a response
